# iterating on vcf file using cyvcf2

Tags: python, csv, iterator, vcf-variant-call-format

I want to create a new csv file that will have some rows of the vcf file (chrom pos ref alt and GT from its samples). But I have troubles getting the GT values. When i do the print commented in the code below, I get an error, even tho I used this webpage (https://pyvcf.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.6/INTRO.html) to create it. What should I write in the vcf_records.append() after alt so that I have all the GT values there? I would appreciate any help!! Thanks!

```
    def foo(vcf_file, input_csv_file, output_csv_file, num_lines=10000):
    
        csv_df = pd.read_csv(input_csv_file, sep=';')
    
        vcf_reader = cyvcf2.VCF(vcf_file)
        total_records_vcf = num_lines
    
        vcf_records = []
        for i, vcf_record in tqdm(enumerate(vcf_reader), total=total_records_vcf):
            chrom = vcf_record.CHROM
            pos = vcf_record.POS
            ref = vcf_record.REF
            alt = vcf_record.ALT[0]
            for sample in vcf_record.samples:
                print(sample['GT']) #this throws an error: AttributeError: 'cyvcf2.cyvcf2.Variant' object has no attribute 'samples'

    
            vcf_records.append({'chrom': chrom, 'pos': pos, 'ref': ref, 'alt': alt, ...#here i need to add the GT values for all samples})

... rest of the code
```

Comment: maybe first check `print(sample)` instead of `print(sample['GT'])`. Maybe file doesn't have `sample['GT']`. Or maybe it has it as `sample.GT`

Comment: or mayby it has `vcf_record.GT` instead fo `sample.GT`

Comment: All of these does not work. When I change the loop into "for sample in vcf_reader.samples" it finally works, but then again neither sample['GT'], nor sample.GT work and I need the GT values for all samples :(

Comment: all this may suggest that you don't have `GT` in your data. Did you use `print()` to see what you really have in variables?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I checked in the debugger and also according to this https://brentp.github.io/cyvcf2/docstrings.html I should use vcf_record.genotypes however it gives me an array that I do not really understand instead of eg '0|1'. This is because I use cyvcf2 and not pyvcf, because I do not know why but installing pyvcf package always results with an error for me. I guess I will have to stick with cyvcf2 and try to understand the array first haha